# How to parse/deserialize a JSON string in C# XAML Windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: json, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I am developing a C#/XAML metro application in which I comsume a JSON REST Services. How can I deserialize a JSON response into a text or a custom object?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605667/c-sharp-json-parsing)

Answer (score 6):

The official JSON APIs for **Windows Store Apps** are in the `Windows.Data.Json` namespace:

- `JsonObject.Parse()` or `new JsonOject()` for objects, it works more less like a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).
- `JsonArray.Parse()` or `new JsonArray()` for arrays, it work more less like a [`List<TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).
- `JsonValue.Parse()`, `JsonValue.CreateStringValue()`, `JsonValue.CreateBooleanValue()` or `JsonValue.CreateNumberValue()` for string, boolean, number and null values.

Check some samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770289.aspx

You won't need to add any library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) in other .NET profile, you can add the library to your Windows Store app project via NuGet.

Here are some examples:

1. Object to Json

   var obj = new { Name = "Programming F#", Author = "Chris Smith" };

   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
2. Querying Json

   var json = @"{""Name"": ""Programming F#"",""Author"": ""Chris Smith""}";

   var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

   string name = (string)jObject["Name"]; // Programming F#
3. Json to Array

   string json = @"['F#', 'Erlang', 'C#', 'Haskell', 'Prolog']";

   JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

   foreach (var item in array)
   {
       string name = (string)item;
   }

You can find Json.NET documentation [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

When consuming JSON REST services I've found by far the best way to deserialise the JSON is to use the [HttpContentExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834253%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class which contains ReadAsASync(HTTP Content) alongside HttpClient. This extension class can be found by installing the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client NUGET package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/).

Making a web request and deserialising is then just this simple:

```
private const string baseUri = "https://weu.google.co/";
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync([Your URI]);
var data  = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourClass>();
return data.Value;
```