# Split a text with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

i try to slit a text and put it into a dictionary , the problem i my text doesn't have a a clear structure :
text :

```
{
   "about": "where I'm meant to be...",
   "bio": "Visit my official blog at:\n\nhttp://ABC.com/  \n\nAdd me on Twitter:\n\nhttp://www.ABC.com/ABC",
   "category": "Public figure",
   "is_published": true,
   "location": {
      "street": "",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "state": "CA",
      "country": "United States",
      "zip": ""
   },
   "talking_about_count": 254637,
   "username": "ABC",
   "website": "http://kimkardashian.celebuzz.com/\nhttp://www.twitter.com/kimkardashian\n",
   "were_here_count": 0,
   "id": "114696805612",
   "name": "ABC",
   "link": "http://www.ABC.com/ABC",
   "likes": 0,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "000000000",
      "source": "http://ABC.jpg",
      "offset_y": 0,
      "offset_x": 200
   }
}
```

As you see i have the "," as a delimiter , the problem is that there some composed objects like the :

```
"location": {
      "street": "",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "state": "CA",
      "country": "United States",
      "zip": ""
   },
```

that's why I can't use the `string.Split(' ');` 
i heard about the regular expressions but I don't know how to use them
Is there  any solution to get those information separated into a dictionary or any other structure

Comment: it has a very clear structure you just need the right parser

Comment: that looks like JSON to me.  you might want to try a JSON deserializer.  I think c# has some built in

Comment: I will try this solution , i heard about it 
meanwhile, is there any other solution with the regular expression ?

Comment: [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605667/c-sharp-json-parsing) has a solution that might be useful to you

Comment: You should really look at JSON desirializer, it's very straight forward and you'll end up with a lot less code and less potential bugs.

Comment: ok thank you , i'am searching for a JSON solution

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in a standard format (JSON) and there are parsers already written for it. You can download Json.NET easy through NuGet in Visual Studio.

Regular expressions are a powerful tool that makes pattern matching a lot simpler. For me that's as far as they go. They *can* be used to create parsers and all sorts of other things, but it's complicated.

So you *could* create your own JSON parser using regular expressions, but it'll take a lot of time. It would be like building a lockpick when there is a key available.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptSerializer may satisfy your needs

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonText);
Console.WriteLine(dict["some_number"]);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx