# Splitting a txtfile of JSONs into individual strings of JSON objects

Tags: c#, regex, json

I have trouble using Regex to split a text file of JSON objects into string. The array of JSON objects are downloaded from an url and is meant to be processed by some javascript function. But I want to read them in C#. I have downloaded the file and just need to split it into individual JSON objects. The format of the text file is:

```
{......},{"S":...}
```

So I want to split it into a string[] so each JSON object is a string:

```
{"S":...}
{"S":...}
{"S":...}
{"S":...}
```

I want to leave out the comma that separates them in the original text file.

```
string[] jsons = Regext.Split(txtfile, "\{\"S\":");
```

But this doesn't work. How can I split it correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605667/c-sharp-json-parsing  or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c may help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't aware already this is a great tool http://regexr.com?36u96

Try

```
string[] splits = Regex.Split(txtfile, @"(?<=\}),");
```

Comment: It won't work if there's all sorts of characters in between, it's a starting point and works with his example.  Can easily add \s* or .* to catch other characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`JsonTextReader`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) class provided by the `Newtonsoft.JSON` assembly (acquirable through `NuGet`).

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the correct answer and I will look into this.