# Unable to Parse this Json string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I tried using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize this json string, but I'm not getting the desired output.
my json string is

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"key": "Residential Homeowner",
"i18nText": "unknown message code DB_ENUM_UserType_residentialhomeowner",
"i18nKey": "DB_ENUM_UserType_residentialhomeowner"
},
{
"id": 8,
"key": "VAR Dealer \/ Builder",
"i18nText": "unknown message code DB_ENUM_UserType_vardealer\/builder",
"i18nKey": "DB_ENUM_UserType_vardealer\/builder"
},
{
"id": 2,
"key": "Administrator",
"i18nText": "unknown message code DB_ENUM_UserType_administrator",
"i18nKey": "DB_ENUM_UserType_administrator"
},
{
"id": 9998,
"key": "TempGuidUser",
"i18nText": "unknown message code DB_ENUM_UserType_tempguiduser",
"i18nKey": "DB_ENUM_UserType_tempguiduser"
},
{
"id": 9999,
"key": "GuidUser",
"i18nText": "unknown message code DB_ENUM_UserType_guiduser",
"i18nKey": "DB_ENUM_UserType_guiduser"
}
]
```

I just want the value of key when value of id=1. Generally json starts with `{}`(curly bracket) but here it is like `[]`(square bracket). I've seen many examples but none worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON Object Array with Json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192357/deserializing-json-object-array-with-json-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only interested in a single value from that larger JSON value, you may want to try [Linq to JSON](http://json.codeplex.com/) which would allow you to query over the JSON without deserializing everything.

Example:

```
JArray values = JArray.Parse(json);

string key;
var keyObject = values.FirstOrDefault(p => (int)p["id"] == 1);
if (keyObject != null)
{
     key = (string)keyObject["key"];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Generally json starts with `{}` (curly bracket), but here it is like `[]` (square bracket).

This is because you got an array of objects, not a single object. Arrays are serialized with square brackets around them. You should deserialize it into an array, and then grab the object at the index of interest.

Comment: i tried using this class. but it is not working :(
public class userType
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string i18nText { get; set; }
        public string i18nKey { get; set; }
        
    }

Comment: @SumitChourasia The class looks right. How did you call Newtonsoft's deserializer? Something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>`?

Answer (score 6):

This is a related post that addresses JSON parsing in C#: [C# JSON Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605667/c-sharp-json-parsing).

If the brackets are a problem, simply use:

```
string json = inputJson.Trim().Trim('[',']');
```

If the id can have a minimum value of 1, then this should work:

```
string GetKey(string inputJson)
{
    string key = inputJson.Substring(inputJson.IndexOf("key")+5);
    key = key.Substring(key.IndexOf("\""), key.IndexOf(",")-key.IndexOf("\""));
    key = key.Trim('\"');
    return key;
}
```

Comment: I just want the value of key when value of id=1.

Comment: This is too much complicated. :(

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but implementation with linq is very simple :)

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is to define a json object array. Your output should be an array. Traverse through the array like:

```
for(var i=0; i<output.Length; i++)
{
    if(output[i].id == "1") // desired id
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output[i].key);// use it as you wish
    }
}
```

and use the found objects `key`.

Comment: I just wanted to give you an idea of how you would approach the problem. @ledbutter's solution is of course the ideal one ;)